# Python – Computing values in a loop and requiring the values to be 0 or larger

Tags: python, loops

In the following Python loop I need that `r[i]` remains 0 or larger. So if `r[i]` is calculated to be smaller than 0, it must instead be set to 0.

```
for i in range(N):
    
    a[i],b[i],r[i] = [A[t] * a[i-1] + B[t] * b[i-1] + C[t] * r[i-1]
    for t in range(3)]
```

I would really appreciate help with this! I have tried `max(x,0) for x in r[i]`, but I always get thrown some kind of error.

Comment: There is probably a solution for this in the context of a list comprehension. However, you will make life much easier for yourself and anyone else who may have to maintain your code if you break this all down into a simple for loop where it will be easy to test for the condition you describe

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra line to fix `r[i]` if necessary:

```
for i in range(N):
    a[i], b[i], r[i] = [A[t]*a[i-1] + B[t]*b[i-1] + C[t]*r[i-1] for t in range(3)]
    r[i] = max(r[i], 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to have done the job! Grüße von Wien nach Stuttgart :)

Comment: You'll need to do more than that unless the arrays a, b & c have already been instantiated to an appropriate size (IndexError). Also, on the first iteration of the list comprehension the calculation will try to evaluate r[-1] which I doubt is what's expected

Comment: Thanks! Arrays a, b, r are np.zeros(N) and arrays A, B, C are np.arrays of the shape (3,). When I run the code it doesn't throw me an error.

Comment: @Suttungr Hehe, Grüße!